# Our app lags "randomly" due to Disk I/O issues?

Tags: linux, nginx, hard-drive, load-balancing, database

We have made an app that requires hundreds of images downloaded for each user every day.

Our basic server setup is as follows: Loadbalancer -> Nginx -> Databaseserver

However, our app "randomly" lags.

It seems to have a relation with the Disk I/O. **Every time it has spikes, the app lags.** Here are some images to show the problem.

[image: graph]

[image: graph2]

What can cause this? And most importantly: **How can I fix this?** I honestly don't know where to start. 
Any help is greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: You likely need a faster disk subsystem.

Answer (score 0):

You really have two options:

1. Get faster disk
2. Add a lot more RAM (so more things can be cached in memory

You should probably do both of these, as there's a possibility that you're starting to swap, which kills your disk IO.

Comment: We have 14gb free memory
http://imgur.com/GfFZHDl

Comment: Well then you have your answer.

Comment: Why doesn't my SQL use my free memory? How would I utilize it? Here's the config: http://paste.bradleygill.com/index.php?paste_id=1346789

Comment: You're keeping images in your database? Well there's 90% of your problem.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. Where else would I keep them?

Comment: Directly on the filesystem, then keep pointers to the images in your database.

Comment: Oh, ok. That's actually how it is now.

Comment: Are you being sarcastic? Yes, databases are horrible for storing and retrieving binary blobs like images. Yes, it can be done, but it's not going to perform well.